# Make a constraint for SYSDATE minus a date of birth

Tags: sql, oracle

I would love to know what I'm doing wrong ,

I would like to add a CHECK constraint in oracle to make sure a user is over 18

So I did

```
ALTER TABLE User
ADD CONSTRAINT  check_age CHECK(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd')- TO_CHAR(dateOfBirth, 'yyyy/mm/dd')> 18)
```

But Im receiving error

> Cause:    An attempt was made to use a date constant or system variable,
>              such as USER, in a check constraint that was not completely
>              specified in a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement.  For
>              example, a date was specified without the century.
>   *Action:   Completely specify the date constant or system variable.
>              Setting the event 10149 allows constraints like "a1 > '10-MAY-96'",
>              which a bug permitted to be created before version 8.

Why it's wrong?

I still don't understand why I can't add it and I would kindly love if someone can explain it to me

Thanks

Comment: Oracle does not allow you to use `sysdate` for a constraint, because that can only be checked when the record is created.

Comment: As an alternative you can use a Trigger

Comment: As a general philosophy, it doesn't really make sense to have "constraints" that may or may not be satisfied depending on whether they are evaluated "now" or "ten minutes from now" (literally, since SYSDATE has a time-of-day component). The same condition, evaluated today or tomorrow, should lead to the same outcome.

Comment: Apart from the fact that `sysdate` isn't allowed in a check constraint, `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd')- TO_CHAR(dateOfBirth, 'yyyy/mm/dd')` is completely wrong. You can't subtract one string from another. To get the difference between two dates, simply use `sysdate - dateOfBirth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in Oracle 11g, while you can't directly use `sysdate` in a constraint, you could get the same effect with a virtual column:

```
create function over_18 ( 
    p_birth_date in User.dateOfBirth%type
) return varchar2 deterministic is

begin
    return case when months_between(sysdate, p_birth_date) /12 > 18 then 'Y' else 'N' end;
end over_18;
/

alter table User add (over_18_ind as (cast(over_18(dateOfBirth) as varchar2(1))));
/

alter table User add constraint check_age check (over_18_ind = 'Y');
/
```

Based on an article [here](http://rwijk.blogspot.ca/2007/12/check-constraints-with-sysdate.html).
Even if Oracle allowed you to use `sysdate` in a constraint, your constraint wouldn't work anyway, since the formats you converted your dates to can't be implicitly cast back to numbers to subtract (I supplied an alternate age check).

Comment: Thank you , I wasn`t aware of that , because Oracle allow us to use SYSDATE in any normal query I just didn't know It was forbidden in a constraint